Using API , URI giving page not found error
I am using Edamam and trying to link to details of a recipe, but it says page not found. I have used URI .Can this be issue with the API itself?
https://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_db742742099859a8053b992dd3c1f452

Thanks
